# how to download all contacts onto excel spreadsheet?

Tags: export

I want to download all my contacts onto an excel spreadsheet. I also want to include what group they are in, all the invitations and literally all the information I have on there. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you install [EXPORT TO NATIVE EXCEL](https://civicrm.org/extensions/export-native-excel) or [EXPORT TO EXCEL](https://civicrm.org/extensions/export-excel) extension and find contacts and select export contact from actions list and export all primary fields or the fields you want to export.

Export contact doc: https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/common-workflows/exporting-your-contacts/

Comment: or you just use civicrm inbuilt export and then open the csv in to excel - or is that a problem that excel now has?